# Sending SIGTERM signal to static worker due to timeout of 60 seconds. Subsequent errors may be a result of the worker exiting

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".   {dispatch: function, subscribe: , getState: , replaceReducer: ..., @@observable: }[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG9Q1.png)
when I try to making build of my next js app. I also try to use "use server" in different components but it is no working for me.
this is my next. config. mjs file.  how to build time error.

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
 const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: ['res.cloudinary.com'],
  },
}
 
export default nextConfig;
```

Comment: Please post the error as a text, ant an screenshot.